# how to know if a module is actually being displayed under active menu item

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In my template's index.php I put code:

```
<?php
if ($this->countModules('position-8')) {
    if($this->countModules('position-7')) $wdth = 660;
        else $wdth = 890;
?>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-8" style="widemodule" width=$wdth />
<?php }; ?>
```

But second condition is always becomes true because I have a module in position-7 on some other page. How to know that module in position-7 is not only exists and active but actually being displayed on *this* very page under current menu item?

Comment: it doesn't matter if it exists on some other page, your statement will evaluete to `true` only if the module should be loaded for the current page. maybe you can put more code and try to explain your problem in more details

Comment: just on a side note, remove the `;` at the end if your `if` statement

Comment: Sorry people I've discovered the point of my difficulties. I've been mixed up with php and Joomla mark-up code. The wrong piece of code is
`width=$wdth`
This would work in PHP but obviously will not work in Joomla mark-up :)
The solution is `width="<?php echo $wdth;?>"` Thank you!